# eyecon ColorPicker with jquery Clone

Tags: jquery, colors

I'm trying to duplicate two inputs and add the Eyecon Color picker to duplicated inputs.
After duplication, when i'm trying to click on the input add select a color, the color is assigned to the previous input, not to the current one.
Thank you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/colorpicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorpicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.color').ColorPicker({
        onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
            jQuery(el).val(hex);
            jQuery(el).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            jQuery(el).ColorPickerHide();
        },
        onBeforeShow: function () {
            jQuery(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
        }
    });
    jQuery(".cloneTableRows").live('click', function(){
        var thisTableId = 'fontmanager';
        var lastRow = jQuery('#'+thisTableId + " tr:first");
        var newRow = lastRow.clone(true);
        jQuery('#'+thisTableId).append(newRow);
        jQuery('#'+thisTableId + " tr:last td:last span").css("visibility", "visible");
        jQuery(newRow).find("input").each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass("color")){
                jQuery(this).ColorPicker({
                    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                        jQuery(el).val(hex);
                        jQuery(el).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                        jQuery(el).ColorPickerHide();
                    },
                    onBeforeShow: function () {
                        jQuery(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    jQuery(".delRow").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parents("tr").remove();
        return false;
    });        
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
.remove {color:#cc0000}
.input{ border: solid 1px #006699; padding:3px}
.x{width:50px;margin-right:10px;}
.y{width:50px;margin-right:10px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="fontmanager">
    <tr class="clone">
        <td class="font_color"><input type="text" name="color1[]" class='color'/></td>
        <td class="font_shadow"><input type="text" name="color2[]" class='color'/>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:transparent !important; border-bottom:0px;border-right:0px !important;"><span class="delRow" style="visibility: hidden;">X</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>  
<p><a href="#" class="cloneTableRows">Add More</a></p>
```

A working example here: [link](http://78.96.152.240/!/)

Comment: A working example? Where? Your link takes me to a page asking me to download a `.zip` file. Please post code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using the incorrect way to assign it's events.

so you are actually assigning the event e.g.`click` and then cloning it. however the event is only registered for the original input. therefore the clone does not know what to do with it because it has not been assign.

you can use the `live()` method when assigning the events so it checks for future references.

u might need to also use `die()` before the `live()` to cancel previews instructions.

if the above does not make sense then post a sample of your code so we can try and re write it.

Comment: I've added the code in the first post. I'm using live() when i'm cloning the row.